# TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, anaconda3, cudnn

I have been trying to set up a virtual environment on the HPC Cluster, but hitting a wall everytime when it comes to tensorflow using GPU.

`module load python3.8/3.8 eval "$(conda shell.bash hook)" conda activate graphgan`

After this I use the following commands to set up the environment

`conda install -c conda-forge cudatoolkit=11.2 cudnn=8.1.0`

When i try to `import tensorflow as tf` it shows the following error

`2024-01-26 23:06:17.968937: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193]                                                                                                  This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (on                                                                                                 eDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:                                                                                                   AVX2 AVX512F FMA To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate comp                                                                                                 iler flags. 2024-01-26 23:06:18.289070: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:2981]                                                                                                  Unable to register cuBLAS factory: Attempting to register factory for plugin cu                                                                                                 BLAS when one has already been registered 2024-01-26 23:06:20.132284: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_lo                                                                                                 ader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer.so.7'; dlerror: libnvinfe                                                                                                 r.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory; LD_LIBRARY_PA                                                                                                 TH: /opt/ohpc/pub/apps/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib:/home/vanshg.phy21.iitbhu/.conda/                                                                                                 envs/graphgan/lib/ 2024-01-26 23:06:20.132710: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_lo                                                                                                 ader.cc:64] Could not load dynamic library 'libnvinfer_plugin.so.7'; dlerror: li                                                                                                 bnvinfer_plugin.so.7: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;                                                                                                  LD_LIBRARY_PATH: /opt/ohpc/pub/apps/anaconda3/envs/py38/lib:/home/vanshg.phy21.                                                                                                 iitbhu/.conda/envs/graphgan/lib/ 2024-01-26 23:06:20.132755: W tensorflow/compiler/tf2tensorrt/utils/py_utils.cc:                                                                                                 38] TF-TRT Warning: Cannot dlopen some TensorRT libraries. If you would like to                                                                                                  use Nvidia GPU with TensorRT, please make sure the missing libraries mentioned a                                                                                                 bove are installed properly.`

I know this will run my code without any issues but i want to use GPU acceleration. Could anyone please tell me what should I do to solve this

I was expecting for the GPU to get detected, as it did in the tutorial I saw. Instead it started throwing errors. I also checked in the directory it mentions and indeed the files were missing. What are the extra libraries that i have to install to make this work?